# В чем различие между регистр и [регистр]?

Tags: ассемблер

Читаю учебник. Понятно что без скобок - это запись в определенный регистр, а со скобками?

Пример кода:

```
MOV DX, 0Ah
MOV DX, [0Ah]
MOV DX, BX
MOV DX, [BX]
MOV [BX], DX
MOV BX, DX
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как я понимаю, данная команда

```
MOV DX, 0Ah
```

заносит непосредственное значение `0Ah` в регистр `DX`

В то время как данная команда

```
MOV DX, [0Ah]
```

заносит в регистр `DX` значение, хранящееся со смещением `0Ah` в сегменте данных, адресуемым регистром `DS`. То есть загружает в регистр `DX` значение, хранящееся по адресу `DS:0Ah`

То же самое верно и для этих команд

```
MOV DX, BX
MOV DX, [BX]
```

В первой команде

```
MOV DX, BX
```

значение из регистра `BX` загружается в регистр `DX`

В то время как во второй команде

```
MOV DX, [BX]
```

значение хранящееся по адресу `DS:BX` загружается в регистр `DX`.

Comment: откуда берется значение сегмента?

Comment: @MaximPro  Я написал же, что из регистра DS.

Comment: почему именно из Data Segment?

Comment: @MaximPro  На самом деле тот сегмент, который адресуется в данный момент регистром DS. Вы должны смотреть формат команды MOV.

Comment: если я буду писать так: MOV DX, DS:[BX] - тогда я понимаю что идет обращение к DS, а вообще как понимать к какому сегментному регистру идет обращение?

Comment: @MaximPro Как я уже сказал, вы должны смотреть форматы команды MOV. Эта команда имеет форматы либо пересылки непосредственного значения, либо регистра, либо данных из памяти. В последнем случае в команде подразумевается использование регистра DS

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Это синтаксис MASM, который указывает, что величину нужно трактовать как адрес, а не как непосредственное значение.

```
MOV DX, 0Ah   ; загрузить в регистр DX значение 10 = 0Ah
MOV DX, [0Ah] ; загрузить в регистр DX значение, лежащее по адресу 10
MOV DX, BX    ; скопировать в регистр DX значение регистра BX
MOV DX, [BX]  ; загрузить в регистр DX значение, лежащее по адресу,
              ; который хранится в регистре BX
MOV [BX], DX  ; записать по адресу, который хранится в регистре BX, значение
              ; из регистра DX
MOV BX, DX    ; скопировать в регистр BX значение регистра DX
```

Разница между  `MOV DX, BX` и `MOV DX, [BX]` такая же, как между `d = b` и `d = *b` в языке C.

Comment: и вот смотрите как мне понимать запись MOV [BX], DX

Comment: @MaximPro записать по адресу, находящемуся в `BX`, значение из `DX`.

Comment: @MaximPro: Дописал.

Comment: @VladD а почему, кстати, именно MASM? В TASM ведь это так же работает.

Comment: @Regent: Угу, правда. И TASM тоже. Но синтаксис вроде из MASM'а.

Comment: @VladD Вижу, смотрите товарищи сверху написали вместо адрес, смещение, я конечно понимаю что в процессоре адресация идет через сегмент:смещение, то есть получается мы не указываем сегмент, а указываем смещение, тогда откуда он возьмет значение сегмента?

Comment: @MaximPro: по умолчанию берётся `DS`.

Comment: @VladD а как понимать по умолчанию или по-другому?

Comment: @MaximPro: Если нет явного указания сегмента, то берётся DS. Если есть явное указание сегмента, то берётся оно.

Comment: @VladD спасибо!

Comment: @MaximPro: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

`[value]` означает смещение относительно `DS:0` сегмента данных или адрес.